# Check if element has no children with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if element has no children set parents element `display:none` property.

But my js is not working as expect where is my mistake ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (!$('#detay-main-carousel').children('.carousel-inner').length>1) {
     $('#detay-main-carousel').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="detay-main-carousel" style="background:turquoise;">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    This is the slider.....
  </div>
</div>

<div id="detay-main-carousel" style="background:yellow;">
    This is the slider.....
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: two divs have same ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The id `detay-main-carousel` is duplicate.

Also `! ..children('.carousel-inner').length > 1` should be:

`! ..children('.carousel-inner').length` OR `children('.carousel-inner').length < 1` OR `children('.carousel-inner').length === 0`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.detay-main-carousel').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).children('.carousel-inner').length) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="detay-main-carousel" style="background:turquoise;">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    This is the slider.....
  </div>
</div>

<div class="detay-main-carousel" style="background:yellow;">
    This is the slider.....
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `!` operator has a higer precedence than `>`, so you should write it differently:

```
if ($('#detay-main-carousel').children('.carousel-inner').length<=1) {
```

which would be the exact opposite of the `>1` check. But reading your question, you would want to test for no such children at all (excluding 1):

```
if ($('#detay-main-carousel').children('.carousel-inner').length == 0) {
```

Note that `$('#detay-main-carousel')` will only match the first occurrence since `id` values are supposed to be unique. Better replace your `id` values with classes, so they don't have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  if ($('#detay-main-carousel').children('.carousel-inner').length < 1) {
     $('.detay-main-carousel').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="detay-main-carousel" style="background:turquoise;">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    This is the slider.....
  </div>
</div>

<div id="detay-main-carousel" style="background:yellow;">
    This is the slider.....
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase what is your desired output ?

Comment: if element has no children than hide parents